# React native firestore not uploading data after changing google account

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I made an app using firestore and react-native, and it worked fine.
I recently decided to change the google account I made the app with, and updated the google-services.json with the new credentials, however now it stops working.

```js
firestore().collection(''+now.getFullYear()+''+(now.getMonth()+1))
        .doc(''+now.getDate()+''+now.getHours()+''+now.getMinutes()+''+now.getSeconds()).set(
          {
            time: Date(),
            point: blob
          }
        ).then(()=>{
          console.log('Uploaded data')
          status('Uploaded')
        })
```

This is the code where I'm adding data the .then function runs and returns Uploaded data however on the firebase console there is no data added.

How do I go about debugging this and finding the exact issue? or could someone point out if I've made an error somewhere, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Could try adding

```
.catch(error => {
console.log(error)
})
```

so it would be

```
firestore().collection(''+now.getFullYear()+''+(now.getMonth()+1))
        .doc(''+now.getDate()+''+now.getHours()+''+now.getMinutes()+''+now.getSeconds()).set(
          {
            time: Date(),
            point: blob
          }
        ).then(()=>{
          console.log('Uploaded data')
          status('Uploaded')
        }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
    })
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately no errors were output :/